# Object of class could not be converted to string?

Tags: php, xml, soap

I'm working a project and i didn't solve that problem.

I have that function, everything okey but when i run this code i take "Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Object of class Modul could not be converted to string in" error. What can i do for this problem ?

```
function gelenBelgeleriAl()
    {

        $result = array();
        try
        {
            $client = new SoapClient($this->servis_url);
            $client->__setSoapHeaders($this->soapHeader($this->kullanici_adi,$this->sifre));
            $sonuc = $client->gelenBelgeleriAl (
              array('vergiTcKimlikNo'=>'1111111',
                    'belgeTuru'=> 'FATURA',
                      'parametreler'=>array(
                      'vergiTcKimlikNo'=>'1111111',
                      'sonAlinanBelgeSiraNumarasi'=>'0',
                      'belgeTuru'=> 'FATURA',
                      'erpKodu'=>"$this->$erp_kodu",
                    )


              )
            );
            
            $result['status']="success";
            $result['result']=$sonuc->return;
            
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            
            $result['status']="error";
            $result['error_messsage']=$e->getMessage();
           
        }
        return $result;
    }
    
}

$modul = new Modul();
?>
<pre>
    <?php
    print_r($modul->gelenBelgeleriAl())
    ?>
</pre>
```

I don't have a idea how can i solve, thanks for help everyone.

Comment: Are you sure the error comes from this bit of code? That error usually comes from an echo or print, which is not the same as print_r

Comment: I don't understand your code. You call `gelenBelgeleriAl()` function on `$client` variable...? But `$client` variable is a SoapClient Object...?

Comment: @Juan Which means their SOAP API probably has that function. Though we don't know the API, so we can only guess.

Comment: yes i'm sure, this project about wsdl service. It takes some information on webservice then return. but this function not working correctly. I tried another function it worked. I think this function convert has some problem

Comment: Yes this is SOAP api. $client variable is a SoapClient Object true.

Comment: @aynber We agree but I find it strange to call a function from an API that has the same name as the function that was written

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: Do we have all the necessary code in front of you to help you...? I am not sure.